# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' on geoserver

Tags: javascript, tomcat, openlayers, geoserver

```
map.on('singleclick', function (evt) {
document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = "Nhìn thấy dòng này thì làm lại đi :) !!!";
var view = map.getView();
var viewResolution = view.getResolution();
var source = hcm.getSource();
var url = source.getFeatureInfoUrl(
evt.coordinate, viewResolution, view.getProjection(),
{ 'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/json', 'FEATURE_COUNT': 50 });
if (url) {
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: url,
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: 'json',
success: function (n) {
var content = "<table>";
for (var i = 0; i < n.features.length; i++) {
var feature = n.features[i];
var featureAttr = feature.properties;
content += "<tr><td>Tên quận:" + featureAttr["name_2"]
+ "</td><td>Số hiệu quận:" + featureAttr["id_2"]
+"</td></tr>"
}
content += "</table>";
$("#info").html(content);
}
});
}
});
```

This is my code to get features.

How can I resolve this problem? I write this code in order to create a WebGIS based on OpenLayers library and GeoServer. But when I try getting features of layers, I have a problem. I can't resolve it! help me, please!

[this is my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6oHF.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are some plugin extensions Available for your browser.

Goto Setting -> Addon  and search for Access Control Allow Origin

Install It And Activate It The  Refresh Your Page!

Comment: Did you activated it before reloading your project?What browser you use?  I have the same problem 2 days ago and i fixed it with addon

Comment: thanks, but I don't use this your way. I inserted several lines of command into conf/web.xml. I'm using apache tomcat with GeoServer run on Google.